# Flutter: showing a dialog at startup

Tags: flutter

I'm quite familiair with Flutter by now but I can't wrap my head around this.

I want to show a dialog on the first launch in a `State<T>` class where `T` is a stateful widget. the dialog contains some short instructions about how to use the app. But doing this logic in the `build` method throws an error, as well as in the `initState` as in the `didChangeDependencies` method.

So where (or rather when) could I possibly call the following logic

```
if(someCondition)
   showDialog(...);
```

Without getting the following error

> The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(state: _FutureBuilderState#66844):
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

> This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can
> be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of
> its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
> the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
> dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might
> not visit this widget during this build phase. The widget on which
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
> Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#27d99]   state:
> OverlayState#4aeab(entries: [OverlayEntry#3c67c(opaque: true;
> maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#564f9(opaque: false;
> maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#7b46b(opaque: false; maintainState:
> false), OverlayEntry#81c9d(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]) The
> widget which was currently being built when the offending call was
> made was: FutureBuilder   state: _FutureBuilderState#66844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your widget is completely built before attempting to show a dialog

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    showDialog(
      // ...
    );
  });
}
```